# Gledhill 450 Torrent RE

Tags: plumbing, boiler

What is the top pipe connected to my Gledhill Torrent 450 RE thermal store?

[image]

It comes out of the very top of the tank. Not on the side but right on the top in the centre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [installation and service manual](http://www.gledhill.net/pdfmanuals/Building%20Products/Torrent%20Range%20Iss%202.pdf), it appears to run to a feed and expansion tank to allow the water in your system to expand and contract safely as it heats and cools.